# Want to know little info about enabling Asynchronous Request Processing in Apache Server?

Tags: apache, asynchronous, request

I'm working upon Paypal integration for our website. As we know, we will provide IPN URL for every orders processing through Paypal, Last week, I have given a server URL for the Paypal Notification and also using that, I have processed the payments.

But, today, when i shifted my projects into an another server, where i have implemented the same IPN system. But I dont get the Notification for the same URL, in my new server. It seems that my new apache server doesn't support Asynchronous Request Processing.

What can i do to make my server to process Asynchronous Requests. Anyone please let me know, how can i do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The "asynchronous" in the word doesn't refer to a feature that has to be activated in Apache. It's just that PayPal sends the request whenever it's ready, and your script calling it has no way of telling when that is.

Most likely, the server move changed something in the server URL. Try out some of the requests that you are telling PayPal to do manually and see what happens and what errors you get.

Comment: Hi Pekka,


Yes I hv changed the IPN URL, since I hv shifted my Project from one server to another Server. But, Problem which i'm facing is as follows: 

In my previous IPN URL, I got some responses to be logged thru the IPN URL. But, in my present server, I dont get any responses from Paypal thru my IPN URL. 

Also I never changed anything in my code. Actual problem is that I dont receive any response from Paypal through the URL which I have Specified during transaction.

It seems that its because of Server only. Seems like server rejecting the Asynchronous response from Paypal. 


Thanks

Comment: @Mohan as said, try making some requests yourself (as if you were PayPal) and see what the server says. Then you can look into the `error.log` file to see what goes wrong

Comment: Hi Pekka, Yeah, If i access the same URL through my browser. Its working, also i hv got some response to be logged. But, when you give the same URL to Paypal for IPN, I dont get any response to be logged. Actually, it seems like Paypal doesn't throw any Notification. Thanks

Comment: @Mohan go through your error.log file to see whether there is anything else. Also make sure the URL  is reachable from outside your network. If all that doesn't help, I'm afraid I don't know what this could be - you may have to talk to PayPal!